# Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3000/’)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, cors

I was recently trying to understand how CORS works, so I setup 2 local servers
to check if I can cross send data between them

localhost:3000 looks like this:

> ```
> const express = require('express');
> const app=express();
>
> app.use(express.json());
>
> app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
>     res.sendFile('public/index.html',{root:__dirname})
> });
>
>
>   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,()=>{
>     console.log('Listening at Port 3000...');
>  });
> ```
>
> and it's index.html looks like this:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>     <title>Document</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <button onclick="others()">get Others data</button>
> <script>
>     function others(){
>       fetch('http://localhost:3100/',{
>         method: "POST",
>         headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:3000/'},
>         body: JSON.stringify({stat:'good'})
>       })
>      .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
>      .then(function(data){ console.log(JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
>     }
> </script>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

localhost:3100 looks like this:

> ```
> const express = require('express');
> const  cors = require('cors')
> const app=express();
>
> app.use(express.json());
> app.use(cors({
>   origin: 'http://localhost:3000/'
> }));
>
> app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
>   res.json({data:"data from 3100 server!"});
>
> });
>
>   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3100,()=>{
>     console.log('Listening at Port 3100...');
>  });
> ```

but when I run the 2 servers simultaneously and make the fetch from localhost:3000 it shows this error:

[image]

I'm a bit new to this can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Remove the `/` at the end of origin***.

It'll work because there is a difference between `http://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:3000/`.

Trailing slash when accessing a file will always look for `index` file.

So, instead of this:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000/'
}));
```

Use this:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));
```

Comment: Also, you might wanna add ```http://127.0.0.1:3000``` to it because  if your server is setting cookies then ```http://localhost:3000 is not equal to ```http://127.0.0.1:300```

Comment: omg it was that simple? thanks you so much